# Redirecting all requests to index.php with exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched everywhere trying to find a solution to something I thought was a particularly common problem, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect all requests via my own CMS (index.php). Here's the htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*(The above mod_rewrite is exactly the same as the code found in a standard Wordpress installation which is why I'm perplexed as to how I cannot find a solution for the following problem)*

I want to add some image processing to my video thumbnails. I have written a php script (video-image.php) that works great but I cannot seem to find a means to redirect the images urls whilst keeping the index.php redirect intact. The code I'm looking for does something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/video/(.*)/(.*).jpg /images/video/video-image.php?video_image_id=$2&video_image_width=$1 [NC]
```

But the above code seems to clash with the mod_rewrite that sends my requests to index.php. It seems I can either redirect the images to video-image.php or redirect my pages to index.php but there must be a way to do both?

I've always found mod_rewrite confusing so apologies if I'm not explaining myself clearly enough. All php scripts function perfectly well without the mod_rewrite so I'm certain it's not a php issue.

If anyone can shed any light on this problem or point me to an answer I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Order your new rule above the existing RewriteCond/RewriteRule block. And you don't generally want the commonplace catch-all RewriteRule *everywhere*. Be more specific, or use the [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource) instead of that copypasta.

Comment: @mario Man, I just had to laugh at myself. Three hours of searching and trying things out and the answer is so simple and makes total sense haha. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The gist of your issue was the ordering of rewrite blocks. You usually put the more specific ones above the general rules. In your case:

```
# specific
RewriteRule ^images/video/(.*)/(.*).jpg /images/…
# generic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

A better approach for Apache 2.4 and later is to use [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource) instead of the RewriteCond/Rule blob:

```
RewriteRule ^images/video/(.*)/(.*).jpg /image
FallbackResource index.php
```

Two more things:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
```

Is something that you should *not* commonly use. Conditional directives make sense in Apaches core configuration. For .htaccess RewriteRule blocks it's less advisable. It's unlikely that mod_rewrite randomly disengages at runtime. And if ever, you'd rather want HTTP 500 errors in your log instead of users seeing 404 Not Found results.

Also `RewriteBase` can shorten some rules, or abstract their residence. But you also shouldn't use it habitually. Instead just prefix `blog/` to your match rules, and assemble all rewrites in the DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess (or better yet VirtualHost section for performance).

Comment: Thanks again for all your help @mario I learned a lot from this post. Seems the FallbackResource method doesn't work for me so my host must be running an older version of apache. I got it working by reordering the rewrite blocks as you suggested but I'll keep FallbackResource in mind for whenever my host get round to updating apache